# Android Studio Gradle CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I m  new in Android Studio. I m using Android Studio 1.0 RC 2  Build #AI-135.1611497 and JDK: 1.8.0_25. Trying to import project, and getting error. Allready tried delete .gradle.. Gradle is setted to Use default gradle wrapper. Any idea to solve it?

```
2014-12-02 10:52:19,643 [3351320]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\ 
2014-12-02 10:52:19,647 [3351324]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\ 
2014-12-02 10:52:19,649 [3351326]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Users\tomas\Android-Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2014-12-02 10:52:19,652 [3351329]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\tomas\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo4461828038903261980.gradle] 
2014-12-02 10:52:21,777 [3353454]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:186)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:361)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:645)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'git''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:196)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:325)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:83)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'git'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:65)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\tomas\Eman\CUCKOO-AN"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Read the trace please, is clear enough, "Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\tomas\Eman\CUCKOO-AN"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: If you are importing an eclipse project to gradle you may get the above error. Check the following link to know more about migrating projects from eclipse to studio.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: @SubinM It is project from Android Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was on a path to Git.

in Android studio
 Goto file --->settings-->versioncontrol--->Git--> give the path of git.exe

*Correct this one:*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

user credentials 
Goto file--->settings-->GitHub-> give username and password

Comment: how do you change the git path?

Comment: in Android studio...
Goto file--->settings--->Git--> give the path and
For github user credentials
Goto file--->settings--->GitHub--> give username and passord

Comment: I'm using SourceTree, with embedded git... Im using this location: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\cmd\git.exe

It worked perfectly, like correctly showing annotations etc. But I'm still receiving the same error "CreateProcess error=2"

Answer (score 4):

Try to comment all 'git' commands in your build.gradle file

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the Git binary folder (the folder containing git.exe) to your system PATH.
This resolve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since android studio is still referring to jdk1.7.0_40 change its path

**Goto Files->Other Settings->Default Project Structure.**

**Under Platform Settings Select Android sdk...under JDK 
location change C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40 to C:\Program Files\Java\1.8.0_25.**

This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Lalson http://blog.csdn.net/aliaooooo/article/details/39338027 try this link this is in chinees use translator to translate check if it helps.

Comment: hi ,I am facing the same problem. this solution is not solving problem... Please suggest me any other solution plz...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while working with a new project in gradle, initially it was working fine but **after initalizing project directory as git repo** IntelliJ IDEA started throwing this error, **removing .git folder worked for me** and then re-initalizing project dir as git repo worked fine second time

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back and I found out Kaspersky antivirus was moving some files to quarantine. Check your antivirus and restore any wrongly flagged files